# it says that the value of this expressions must be constant

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];

    return 0;
}
```

here it wont let define the arr of size n
the value of n is defined above so n is most propbably a constant right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard

Comment: Your code declares and reads a *variable* (a named object with value that can change as the program is running) not a constant.    `int arr[n]` where `n` is a variable is not valid in standard C++.    The requirement is that `n` would have a value that can be computed during compilation (known as a compile-time constant).

Answer (score 0):

`n` is not a constant. In C++, `n` would only be a constant if it is defined as `const int n`.

If you're reading `n` from `cin` with `cin >> n`, then how can it be a constant? You can't control what the user inputs.

Comment: It is correct what you say but its not that relevant for the question, because also a const variable is not allowed for array size, it must instead be a compile time constant.